# Decrease two custom objects values using reduce operation

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a custom object like the following one.

```
public class Count {
    private int words;
    private int characters;
    //getters & setters && all args constructor

    void Count decrease(Count other) {
       this.words -= other.words;
       this.characters -= other.characters; 
       return this;
    }
}
```

I want to achieve the next result, e.g:

Count book1 = new Count(10, 35);

Count book2 = new Count(6, 10);

the result would be:
Count result = Count(4, 25) -> ([10-6], [35-10])

I tried this solution but it didn't work.

`Stream.of(book1, book2).reduce(new CountData(), CountData::decrease)`

It's possible to achieve this result using reduce operation or another stream operation from java >=8 ?

Comment: I don't think you can use `reduce()`. Subtraction is not associative.

Comment: But you can do something like `Stream.of(book2, bookN).reduce(CountData::increase).map(book1::decrease).orElse(book1)`

Comment: There is no point in processing two objects with a `Stream` in this way. Whatever you write into the body of the reduction function would do its job better and simpler without the surrounding `Stream` operation, when just applied to the two objects directly.

Answer (score 2):

The following ad hoc solution uses a single-element stream of `book2` to be subtracted from a seed initialized with `book1` values:

```java
Count reduced = Stream.of(book2)
    .reduce(new Count(book1.getWords(), book1.getCharacters()), Count::decrease);
```

Here value of `book1` is not affected.

However, for this specific case this can be done without Stream API:

```java
Count reduced = new Count(book1.getWords(), book1.getCharacters())
        .decrease(book2);
```